# How do I complete this implementation of magic bitboards?

Tags: engines, programming, bitboard

I'm currently coding a chess engine in C++, and have run into a bit of trouble with my magic bitboard implementation.

So far, I have a function that calculates blockerBoards (all the possible pieces that can block the rook or the bishop).

From there, I have the following code to take these blockerBoards and convert them into attack tables:

```
bitset<M> mBishopAttacks[64][512]; // 256 K
bitset<M> mRookAttacks[64][4096]; // 2048K

bitset<M> bishopAttacks(bitset<M> blockerBoard, int sq) {
    unsigned long long index = blockerBoard.to_ullong();
    index *= bishopMagics[sq];
    index >>= 64-9
    return mBishopAttacks[sq][index]; //outputs corresponding attack board
}
```

Note that I got the array of magic numbers, bishopMagics[64], from somewhere on the web.

How do I initialize these attack tables, mBishopAttacks and mRookAttacks? Currently, they are empty. Do I simply have to calculate the attack tables for each possible permutation of blockers?

Comment: I assume you know this [wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Bitboards)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably most efficient if I paste my code from my [chess move generator on GitHub](https://github.com/nkarve/surge/blob/master/src/tables.cpp).

```
int ROOK_ATTACK_SHIFTS[64];
Bitboard ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[64];
Bitboard ROOK_ATTACKS[64][4096];

void initialise_rook_attacks() {
    Bitboard edges, subset, index;

    for (Square sq = a1; sq <= h8; ++sq) {
        edges = ((MASK_RANK[AFILE] | MASK_RANK[HFILE]) & ~MASK_RANK[rank_of(sq)]) |
            ((MASK_FILE[AFILE] | MASK_FILE[HFILE]) & ~MASK_FILE[file_of(sq)]);

        ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[sq] = (MASK_RANK[rank_of(sq)]
            ^ MASK_FILE[file_of(sq)]) & ~edges;

        ROOK_ATTACK_SHIFTS[sq] = 64 - pop_count(ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[sq]);

        subset = 0;
        do {
            index = subset;
            index = index * ROOK_MAGICS[sq];
            index = index >> ROOK_ATTACK_SHIFTS[sq];
            ROOK_ATTACKS[sq][index] = get_rook_attacks_for_init(sq, subset);
            subset = (subset - ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[sq]) & ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[sq];
        } while (subset);
    }
}
```

Some comments:

- For each square, the bitboard stored in the attacks table is determined by a complicated cycling algorithm. You start with an empty bitboard `subset`, then manipulate it using the magics and the masks generated previously. This gives you an index. You then initialise the attacks table at `ROOK_ATTACKS[sq][index]` as the bitboard of slider moves from that square, using the initial value of `subset` as the occupation bitboard. `subset` is then updated using the masks, and the loop continues. The nature of the magic numbers is that, starting with `subset=0`, you will cycle through all 4096 indices (not in order), and `subset` will turn into the correct "representative" occupation bitboard for all 4096 of these.
- The value of "9" while bitshifting to calculate the index should *not* be hardcoded. Instead, it should depend on whether the piece is in the centre, on an edge or in a corner, which is what `ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS` and `ROOK_ATTACK_SHIFTS` are for. I believe excluding these is a little-known bug
- Once you have generated the occupation/blockers bitboard for a particular index (running from 0 to 4095 for rooks), you can generate the sliding moves to initialise the attacks matrix in any way you want. I personally used hyperbola quintessence, but using a simple flood fill poses no problems, it's all pregenerated anyway

Unfortunately the chess programming wiki does not seem to be very useful on these matters; you are best off reading the original works and talkchess posts by Pradyumna Kannan et al.

Comment: I am confused about this `subset = (subset - ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[sq]) & ROOK_ATTACK_MASKS[sq];` line. How exactly is it supposed to work, because it doesn't for me?

Comment: @TomGebel could you elaborate on what the issue is? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C++. You claim that `subset` should turn into all possible permutations of the attack mask, but it does not when I try to replicate your example. The attack mask generation is definitely working correctly, I don't see where I could have made a mistake. No matter what square I am indexing, `subset` always turns to `1` and then to `0`. Any ideas?